# token register vs. macro register

Tags: tex-core

Consider the following simple code:

```
\def\@ifundefined#1#2#3{% \cs{UNDEF}{DEF}
    \def\reserved@a{#2}%
    \def\reserved@b{#3}%
    \ifdefined#1
        \let\reserved@c\reserved@b
    \else
        \let\reserved@c\reserved@a
    \fi
    \reserved@c}
```

The same result can be achieved with:

```
\toksdef\tokszero0
\toksdef\tokstwo2
\def\@@ifundefined#1#2#3{% \cs{UNDEF}{DEF}
    \tokszero{#2}%
    \tokstwo{#3}%
    \ifdefined#1
        \let\reserved@c\tokstwo
    \else
        \let\reserved@c\tokszero
    \fi
    \the\reserved@c}
```

Is there any significant difference? (Aside from `\toksdef`.) Which one is preferable?

(I can think of one difference. If either UNDEF or DEF contains `#`, then the macro register version would fail.)

Comment: In eTeX you can imitate toks registers with `\protected\edef\reserved{\unexpanded{#1}}` if I remember correctly. `\toks` is ”faster”, but probably the difference in your use doesn't really matter. In LaTeX3 the macro version is used for almost everything the user does.

Comment: You've marked this as [tag:tex-core] but the use of `\reserved@a` suggests LaTeX ...

Comment: It is usually better to avoid assignment at all (the latex definition of `\@ifundefined` doesn't use assignment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a very complete benchmark, but it should give the idea. Consider the following `testundef.tex` file

```
\catcode`@=11

\def\a@ifundefined#1#2#3{% \cs{UNDEF}{DEF}
  \def\reserved@a{#2}%
  \def\reserved@b{#3}%
  \ifdefined#1%
    \let\reserved@c\reserved@b
  \else
    \let\reserved@c\reserved@a
  \fi
  \reserved@c
}
\toksdef\tokszero0
\toksdef\tokstwo2
\def\b@ifundefined#1#2#3{% \cs{UNDEF}{DEF}
  \tokszero{#2}%
  \tokstwo{#3}%
  \ifdefined#1%
    \let\reserved@c\tokstwo
  \else
    \let\reserved@c\tokszero
  \fi
  \the\reserved@c
}
\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\c@ifundefined#1{% \cs{UNDEF}{DEF}
  \ifdefined#1%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}

\expandafter\let\expandafter\ifundefined\csname\test @ifundefined\endcsname

\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<1000000
  \ifundefined\foo{\relax}{\relax}
  \ifundefined\relax{\relax}{\relax}
  \advance\count255 1
\repeat

\bye
```

I give three possible definitions of `\@ifundefined` and then test them by a command line switch. Here's the session transcript

```
> time pdftex "\def\test{a}\input testundef"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./testundef.tex )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on testundef.log.

real    0m1.871s
user    0m1.844s
sys 0m0.018s

> time pdftex "\def\test{b}\input testundef"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./testundef.tex )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on testundef.log.

real    0m2.308s
user    0m2.277s
sys 0m0.021s

> time pdftex "\def\test{c}\input testundef"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./testundef.tex )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on testundef.log.

real    0m1.518s
user    0m1.490s
sys 0m0.017s
```

It seems that the `\toks` method is the slowest; the final method, with pure expansion, is faster because there is no storing away and retrieving to do.